Which Präposition should I use with Erwartungen?
The phrase I have in mind is actually in Brazilian Portuguese:

Ela fala quais expectativas ela tem para o próximo show.

In English it would be like: She speaks about what are her expectations for the next show.
In German would I write with the Präposition "für"? " She spricht darüber, dass sie ein Fan der Band ist und welche Erwartungen für das nächste Konzert hat.
PS: Please forgive my English and my German, my mother language is Portuguese and I'm still learning.

If you're more comfortable in German then feel free to to ask questions in that language; in which case the answers will also be in German. I don't know if there specific rule that it has to either English or German, but I don't think a lot of other people here are fluent in Portuguese. A useful tool for this kind of question is the DWDS-Wortprofil. Check the section "hat Präpositionalgruppe" for common prepositions used with a particular word. It looks like the options in this case are "für", "von" and "an".

If "für" is correct depends on what exactly you want to say (and, sorry, but I don't speak Portugese).
If you have "Erwartungen für das Konzert" you mean you have expectations for what will happen at the concert but that is something not directly related to the concert. If she expects her appointment to kiss her there, this would be a "Erwartung für" the concert.
Then there is a fixed phrase Erwartungen an etwas haben, which means "to have expectations for sth.". If your expectations are directly related to the concert (e.g. she expects the band to play for at least two hours) then this is the right phrase. So, the sentence you gave as example would read:

Sie spricht darüber, dass sie ein Fan der Band ist und welche Erwartungen sie an das nächste Konzert hat.

This is grammatically correct but sounds a little hmm (for lack of a better word). In informal language (and the rest of the sentence sounds informal) you tend to use verbs, not nouns. Hence "erwarten" instead of "Erwartungen haben":

Sie spricht darüber, dass sie ein Fan der Band ist und was sie vom nächsten Konzert erwartet.

Replacing "Erwartung an" with "Erwartung für" would yield:

Sie spricht darüber, dass sie ein Fan der Band ist und was sie auf dem nächsten Konzert erwartet.


"Er spricht darüber, welche Erwartungen er mit dem nächsten Konzert verbindet",
or
"...., was er sich vom nächsten Konzert erwartet".
"erwarten + von NOUN" is OK.
But this does not work well with the noun "Erwartung".
